# Adding a file in the branch main folder

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have a svn branch "AppTest" and inside a this branch there are the project folder: DAL, BL, ... etc.

I need to put a configuration file in the branch, without put it in a folder. But with eclipse I can't just import a single file but only a folder.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You should "add" the file(and then commit), not "import" it into SVN.